# Why loop over an internal object rather than the object received in a node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following nodejs module example (from the Lynda.com node course) sets a module's `values` object when some information is passed in. Assume the module is called 'flight'.

```
module.exports = function (info) {

    var values = {
        number: null,
        origin: null,
        destination: null,
        departs: null,
        arrives: null,
        actualDepart: null,
        actualArrive: null
    };

    for(var prop in values) {
        if(values[prop] !== 'undefined') {
            values[prop] = info[prop];
        }
    }

    var functions = {
        triggerDepart: function () {
            values.actualDepart = Date.now();
        },
        triggerArrive: function () {
            values.actualArrive = Date.now();
        },
        getInformation: function () {
            return values;
        }
    };

    return functions;

};
```

Example call:

```
var ausdca = {
    number: 382,
    origin: 'AUS',
    destination: 'DCA'
};

var ad = flight(ausdca);

console.log(ad.getInformation());
```

I'm curious to know whether it is important that the developer has chosen to loop over values rather than the info object passed in. Why not do:

```
    for(var prop in info) {
        if(values[prop] !== 'undefined') {
            values[prop] = info[prop];
        }
    }
```

Is this just a stylistic / art of programming choice or is it an important distinction in node / javascript? I would have thought that if you loop over `values`, there will never be an undefined value as null != undefined.

Comment: The author only wants to keep pre-defined keys in the object.

Answer (score 1):

If you loop over `values`, the only possible assignements are the ones for which `values` already has a property.

If you loop over `info`, the user of the module can introduce new properties into `values`.`

Comment: Could you explain why the author wouldn't want new properties in `values`?

Comment: New properties occupy memory. New properties are not used. Then why occupy memory for them?